# Get the name of the java process instead of pid?

Tags: java

`jps.exe` which found on JDK 1.5 and later could monitor all Java process but is there a way to detect the specify command line and terminate the correct pid?

What if the user have JRE, is there a similar code allow us to terminate any process easily?

Prefer to keep the topic on Windows which I am working on.

Answer (score 1):

The `jps` command supports a number of options that modify the output of the command. These options are subject to change or removal in the future.

`-q` Suppress the output of the class name, JAR file name, and arguments passed to the main method, producing only a list of local VM identifiers.

`-m` Output the arguments passed to the main method. The output may be null for embedded JVMs.

`-l` Output the full package name for the application's main class or the full path name to the application's JAR file.

`-v` Output the arguments passed to the JVM.

`-V` Output the arguments passed to the JVM through the flags file (the .hotspotrc file or the file specified by the -XX:Flags= argument).

Pipe the output of `jps` to `grep` or `sed` or `awk` or `perl` or even another Java program for further matching, parsing and action.  On Windows, the easiest way to get those utilities is through Cygwin.

Here are some Microsoft downloadable command line utilities which are useful for working with processes on Windows:

- [pskill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx)
- [pslist](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682.aspx)
- and the rest of the [Sysinternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx)

Comment: I mean if the user doesn't have JDK but JRE, how would they have it?

Comment: jps doesn't come with the JRE.  Could you send them the jps executable?  Would that work?  Maybe the jps executable also needs a JAR from the JDK too?  (I don't know.)  Or come up with some alternative solution.   You could write a custom C program for example that lists and searches for processes.  This would be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

If the user don't have *jps*, you can use *ps*. The command line options for *ps* differs between platforms, see *man ps* on you system. I use *ps -C java -o pid,time,cmd* to list java processes on a CentOS system. Then *kill* to terminate.

Comment: @user217582 - I don't think windows comes complete with a command line utility to kill processes.  I usually use `pslist` and `pskill` when on Windows. You can download them from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx & http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682.aspx